# nodejs ExpressJS webservices serving php cometchat app

Tags: android, node.js, express

I had an expressJS Rest api, and want to use The CometChat Android SDK to consume

webservices from that api.

I'm wondering it is possible to do that ?

any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can consume any RESTful API from Android, including an API written in Node and Express.

The CometChat is a PHP API plus Android and iOS SDKs. So of course you can use any RESTful API in any Android app, including those that also use the CometChat API.

It's not exactly clear what have you tried so far and what are the problems that you experience, but the answer to your question is: Yes, you can use any RESTful API in any Android app - but it doesn't necessarily mean that every SDK will automatically consume every other API.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to consume any RESTful API from android you can use [retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), or you could easily achieve your goal(ChatApp i think) with Firebase.